# PHP Enters "if"although condition can't be true

Tags: conditional-statements

I have a really weird problem and am pretty confused after working on this for a while.
I have this condition

```
        $save_res = $database->saveShift();
        if ($save_res == "SHIFT_CONFLICT") {
            $errors['insertShift'] = "error msg";
            echo $save_res;
            $valid = false;
        } else if ($save_res) {
            $notices['insertShift'] = "success msg";
            $valid = true;
        }
```

Now the weird part is: `$save_res is definitely not "SHIFT_CONFLICT"`, but true or "1" when I echo it (inside of the if statement), but the condition if `$save_res == "SHIFT_CONFLICT"` is true for some reason and the code inside the if statement gets executed.

Comment: First off, use `===`.

Comment: And do not use echo to debug, `var_dump` needs some love.

Comment: true == "SHIFT_CONFLICT" is true but true === "SHIFT_CONFLICT" is false. So use is identical to (===) instead of is euqals to (==) as The Paramagnetic ... mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 if ($save_res == "SHIFT_CONFLICT") {
```

to

```
 if ($save_res === "SHIFT_CONFLICT") {
```